# jquery not working as expected in windows server 2003 R2

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using jquery in my asp.net website. It was working fine in my local system. But when I published it in the server it is not working. My jquery code is as follow,

```
    $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    if ($("#<%=ddlLetterType.ClientID %>").val() == "-1") {
        alert("Please select a letter.");
        $("#<%=ddlLetterType.ClientID %>").focus();
        $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", false);
        return false;
    } else if ($("#<%=ddlLetterType.ClientID %>").val() == "1") {
        if ($("#<%=ddlEmbassyCountry.ClientID %>").val() == "-1") {
            alert("Please select an Embassy Country.");
            $("#<%=ddlEmbassyCountry.ClientID %>").focus();
            $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", false);
            return false;
        } else if ($("#<%=ddlTravelCountry.ClientID %>").val() == "-1") {
            alert("Please select a Travel Country.");
            $("#<%=ddlTravelCountry.ClientID %>").focus();
            $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", false);
            return false;
        } else if ($("#<%=txtEmbassyAddress.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
            alert("Please enter embassy address.");
            $("#<%=txtEmbassyAddress.ClientID %>").focus();
            $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", false);
            return false;
        } else if ($("#<%=txtPassportNo.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
            alert("Please enter passport no.");
            $("#<%=txtPassportNo.ClientID %>").focus();
            $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", false);
            return false;
        } else if ($("#<%=txtPlaceOfMeeting.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
            alert("Please enter place of meeting.");
            $("#<%=txtPlaceOfMeeting.ClientID %>").focus();
            $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", false);
            return false;
        } else if ($("#<%=txtStartDate.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
            alert("Please enter start date.");
            $("#<%=txtStartDate.ClientID %>").focus();
            $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", false);
            return false;
        } else if ($("#<%=txtEndDate.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
            alert("Please enter end date.");
            $("#<%=txtEndDate.ClientID %>").focus();
            $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", false);
            return false;
        } else {
            var parameter = {
                request_no: $("#<%=lblRequestNo.ClientID %>").text(),
                initiator_user_id: $("#<%=hInitiatorUserId.ClientID %>").val(),
                initiatingDate: $("#<%=lblRequestdate.ClientID %>").text(),
                embassy_country_id: $("#<%=ddlEmbassyCountry.ClientID %>").val(),
                embassy_address: $("#<%=txtEmbassyAddress.ClientID %>").val(),
                nationality: $("#<%=lblNationality.ClientID %>").text(),
                passport_no: $("#<%=txtPassportNo.ClientID %>").val(),
                company: $("#<%=lblCompanyName.ClientID %>").text(),
                designation: $("#<%=lblDesignation.ClientID %>").text(),
                joining_date: $("#<%=lblJoiningDate.ClientID %>").text(),
                travel_country_id: $("#<%=ddlTravelCountry.ClientID %>").val(),
                place_of_meeting: $("#<%=txtPlaceOfMeeting.ClientID %>").val(),
                travel_start_date: $("#<%=txtStartDate.ClientID %>").val(),
                travel_end_date: $("#<%=txtEndDate.ClientID %>").val(),
                letter_filename: $("#<%=lblRequestNo.ClientID %>").text() + "_business_letter",
                status: '2',
                hr_letter_type_id: $("#<%=ddlLetterType.ClientID %>").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<%=ResolveUrl("~/HRLetterService.asmx") %>/RegisterHRLetterBusinessData",
                data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    __doPostBack('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") %>', '');
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert("Error in saving the request. Please contact your administrator by sending the screen shot to unify.admin@unilever.com");
                    $(this).attr("disabled", false);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        }
.
.
.
.
```

I haven't posted all the code as the code is fine and there is no error as such. But the only problem is at if statements. The if and else if statements get executed but the else part doesn't get executed. What can be the problem? Could you please help me? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what does the generated JS look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not wrapped in `ready` event callback. If your code is placed in head as is, it will fire before the html exists and will never bind to the elements it is looking for, since they aren't there yet.

```
   $(function(){ // shorthand for $(document).ready(){

       /* html exists, run your code here*/

   })
```

If this doesn't resolve issue, use a browser console to check for errors thrown

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried wrapping my code in ready event callback but still it is not working fine. I even tried to check for error in browser console but I don't get any error also.... The else part is not only being executed...

Comment: if it is only part of your code within `else` that isn't firing then something is different between your development files and server files